# What other vegetables can I roast with asparagus?

Tags: vegetables, roasting

I eat roasted vegetables at least once a week.

I usually combine two or three veggies (broccoli with cauliflower, potatoes with carrots and onions, Brussels sprouts with carrots and parsnips, etc.), toss with olive oil, salt and pepper, maybe some garlic and onion powder or herbs, and roast at 225°C / 450°F for about half an hour.

I would love to add asparagus into the rotation. The problem is that it cooks so much faster than the other veggies I'm used to working with (often just 10-12 minutes at the same temperature).

Is there another vegetable that I can roast with asparagus (aside from "white asparagus"!) that will cook as quickly, or am I stuck with two different roasting times?

Spring vegetables that are available fresh in southern Ontario, Canada would be ideal.

Comment: I just add faster-cooking veggies after some of the time has gone by. So put the usual stuff in 30 minutes before you want to eat, and 15 minutes before you want to eat, add the asparagus and give everything a turn.

Comment: I made roasted vegetables last week: red onion, courgette, asparagus and pepper. I just put the asparagus in with everything else, added plenty of oil and roasted for 30-45 minutes and it was fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest zucchinis. They taste very good with olive oil and they will be ready at the same time as the asparagus.

Answer (score 4):

Vegetable roasting times are somewhat depending on what kind of vegetable it is--broccoli is always going to take longer than spring peas.  But mostly, it is dependent on the size to which you cut them.

So cutting your other vegetables in smaller pieces will help.

Also, you can start, for example, carrots and broccoli, and give them a ten minute head start, then add the asparagus.

Answer (score 3):

Peppers would be a good choice. Slice and clean them (by clean I mean scrape the insides and rinse, especially with hot peppers) Chopped roasted peppers would make a great addition to a cheese sauce to pour over the asparagus as well..